# Rotation matrix covariance to quaternion covariance

Tags: rotations, covariance, quaternions, kalman-filter

Given a $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ with an associated $3 \times 3$ covariance matrix $\mathbf{P}$  how do I compute the associated $4 \times 4$ covariance matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ of the corresponding quaternion $\mathbf{q}$?

The reason for this is that I am using a bunch of rotation matrices estimated by SO(3) Extended Kalman Filters in an Extended Information Filter.

However, I don't know a way of keeping multiple rotation matrices in the state $\mathbf{X}$ of the Extended Information Filter so that the information vector is given by $\mathbf{i} = \mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{X}$. Instead, I want to convert the rotation matrices to quaternions and use the quaternion elements to represent each rotation matrix.

Thus, comes the problem with converting the covariance...

Comment: What exactly does the R covariance matrix represent? E.g. what covariance does $P_12$ represent?  Typically one uses a rotation vector representation and then the covariance is between the vector components. Alternatively, you could use Euler angles, but they are kind of messy in my opinion.

Comment: It is from attitude estimation - $\mathbf{P}$ is the uncertainty representation of the error $\log(\mathbf{R}^{T}\hat{\mathbf{R}})$ where log is the logarithmic map for SO(3) and $\mathbf{R}$ is the true state and $\hat{\mathbf{R}}$ estimated state. The state $\mathbf{R}$ is estimated by $\dot{\mathbf{R}}_{t} = \mathbf{R}_{t}[\omega_{t}]_{\times}$ and here $\omega_{t}$ is angular velocity.

Comment: Yeah I thought about Euler angles initially and indeed it looks very messy. But I dont think I can use my covariance directly even in the Euler angle case? I'm not sure.

Comment: The log map is really 3 degrees of freedom(DOF), maybe use that for state instead of the rotation? I think that it is more or less the same as using quaternions, remember that a rotation quaternion is normalized, so  there are not really 4 DOF.

Comment: @user721481 just curious as to why one don't always use the log map? What is the downside compared to e.g. convert to Euler angles or Quaternions?

Comment: I like the log map. Didn't say there is a down side. There id only a single defenition, as compared to euler angles, which has about a dozen different versions, and it is symmetric in the treatment of the angles, that is, there is no specific order in which the rotations are determined, just exp(Log). However, I seem to remember that there is some ambiguities at large rotations ( near $pi/2$ etc) where quaternions handle it better.

Comment: @user721481 The log map can be seen as a skew-symmetric matrix containing the vector whose direction and magnitude represents the axis of rotation and the angle rotated around that axis respectively. The problem with the log map happens when the magnitude is a multiple of full rotations ($2\,k\,\pi$ with $k\neq0$). Namely, a full rotation is equivalent to no rotation meaning that the axis of rotation is not well defined, which translates to singularities in its dynamics near that value. For more information look at [this paper](http://malcolmdshuster.com/FC_Stuelpnagel_1964_param_SIAM.pdf).

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by "ambiguities at large rotation"

Comment: So you define the error as $[e]_\times = \log(R^\top \hat{R})$. Does this mean that you define the covariance as $P = E[e\,e^\top]$ or $P = E[[e]_\times\,[e]_\times^\top]=E[e^\top e\,I - e\,e^\top]$?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I define it as the first way you describe it: $P=E[ee^{T}]$